# Change NbStepper programmatically ngx/admin

Tags: angular

I am using Nebular stepper. How can I change the steps programmatically?

```html
<nb-stepper orientation="horizontal" #stepper  disableStepNavigation>
   <nb-step label="Site Information">
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this on your component.ts file.

```js
@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: NbStepperComponent;
```

Then do

```js
this.stepper.next();
```

See the documentation [here](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/stepper/api#nbsteppercomponent).